# How can I quit a BlackBerry application when the user selects a menu item?

Tags: java, blackberry

I have an exit button in my application and I want to properly quit the whole application when the button is clicked. Is exit(0) enough to exit the BlackBerry application completely?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to exit a BlackBerry application programmatically:

```
System.exit(0);
```